# Validate route values asp net mvc

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, validation, routes, asp.net-mvc-routing

I would like to validate url before execute controller action.
User run app with url which looks like:

```
https://appAddress/appAdress2/{first}/?secondId=ASD&thirdId=FGH&fourthId=123

"first" and "secondId" values are mandatory and they are string.
"thirdId" and "fourthId" are optional and "thirdId" is string and "fourthId" is int.
```

Can I do this e.g bu use attibute or should I check the values inside controller action ?

```
public ActionResult MyAction()
{
//todo: validation
}
```

I use ASP.NET MVC 5

Comment: Which MVC version you deal with? MVC 5 has attribute routing constraint rule that can be customized to any URL whatever you want, i.e. `{action}/?id2=val2&id3=val3&id4=val4`. Make sure your action method contains 4 parameters too.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto - Actually, RouteAttribute doesn't work with query string values, so that is not possible.

Comment: Unclear what you are asking. You want to "validate" the parameters in what way? What should happen if they don't pass validation? 404 not found? Something else?

Comment: @NightOwl888 If they are wrong, system redirect to error page.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto I use MVC 5

Comment: @NightOwl888 You're right, I mistakenly mixing between attribute routing and composing action method by accident. This can achieved by setting up a route value in `RegisterRoutes` using `MapRoute` with an id for first keyword and a variable holds query string for other 3 keywords. Besides of that, I prefer using `appAdress2/{first}/{second}/{third}/{fourth}` to URL query strings.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to validate the request has all of the necessary information is to check it within your action method.

```
public ActionResult MyAction(string first, string secondId, string thirdId, string fourthId)
{
    if (/* parameters are not valid */)
    {
        // Take invalid action...
        throw new ArgumentException("parameters are invalid");
    }
}
```

The above will throw an exception, which (as long as your error page is configured in web.config) will show the error page. Generally speaking, you are not supposed to inform the user what *specific* error happened for security reasons.

Parameters are passed into the request from the route values and/or query string values automatically by the default value providers. All you need to do is make sure the names (and possibly data types) match those in your route/query string.